# Assembly code isn't working for when i try to add 8 to option label?

Tags: assembly, jasper-jasp-toolkit

So im pretty new to assembly and im trying to use it for JASPer , using assembly through cmd and writting it in notepad.

Im trying to get the hang of assembly by writing a program where if the label "Option" isnt 1 then change it to 9.

However im getting some issues.

Can someone give me a example so im not lost while doing this revision work ?

Im writing it like this:

''' ORG 0000 '''

'''  MOVE Option,$12 '''

''' MOVE $12,A '''

''' MOVE #$1,B

''' CMP Option,B '''

''' BNE Adding '''

''' HALT '''

'' Adding ADD #8,Option ''

''' HALT '''

// dont know if i need to show option as a label for it to work or if thats alright for memory and so on?

i just need abit of advice so i can continue on with my assembly revision

EDITED:

```
   '''ORG 0000'''

   '''MOVE #$2,A'''

   '''MOVE #$9,B'''

   '''CMP A,B'''

   '''JMP DOG'''

   '''HALT'''
```

'''DOG    ADD #2,Option'''

'''Option MOVE Option,$1'''

```
   '''ADD $1,A'''

   '''CMP A,B'''

   '''BNE adding'''
```

'''adding ADD #8,A'''

```
   '''HALT'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to declare `Option` as a data label and reserve some storage for the data as well — that would normally be done with either `DS.W 1` (define storage of 1 word) which will be initialized to 0, or, use `DC.W 100` if you wanted to specify an initial value, here 100.

---

In order to declare `Option` as a data label, you can put it near the beginning, but be sure to jump around it, because you don't want the processor to execute that data as an instruction.  We have to keep the memory being used for code & data separated for things to work properly.  So, something like:

```
       ORIG 0000
       JMP Start          // skip over the data

Option DC.W 100           // data storage

Start  MOVE Option,A      // main code here
```

The processor can only directly address the first 256 words (at 0x00 to 0xFF), so putting the data at the beginning is good for simple variables.  To access data that is beyond the first 256 locations, you would have to use more complex addressing.

---

The default instruction set can only support one memory operand per instruction, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by `MOVE Option,$12`.

Comment: thank you for your help much appreciated